# How do you change file paths in Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm looking at this [sample Angular application](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app).

In the `index.html` file, there are lines like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/angular.js"></script>
```

However, upon closer inspection there are no folders in the project called `static`.

How does this work? How does angular locate these references?

Comment: @AndrewCounts is right; angular does not play with these paths. It cannot, since the browser is using this path to *load* angular. Your server has to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has nothing to do with this. It is the `express` server which takes care of the paths.
Take a look at `server/config.js`. You will see `staticUrl: '/static'` mentioned there.

Now open `server/server.js` *(server.js is the script which runs before anything else runs in the app so all the configuration is done within this file)* and on **line 21** you will see `require('./lib/routes/static').addRoutes(app, config);`. This requires the `static.js` file which instructs the app to use `/static` *(mentioned in the config.js file)* as the path for static files such as CSS and javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

When that HTML file is processed by the browser, the layout engine is making a separate HTTP request to the server to download the resource in question:

```
/static/angular.js
```

Since all of that is handled by the server routing mechanism there doesn't have to be a folder named static in client code. Your example is using Node.js Express routing which **maps /static routes to actual physical paths**.

Here is a piece of code that configures static routes:

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/server/config.js

The important parts are:

```
staticUrl: '/static', // The base url from which we serve static files (such as js, css and images)
```

And the destination folder that /static maps to:

```
distFolder: path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/dist'), // The folder that contains the application files (note that the files are in a different repository) - relative to this file
```

Per the documentation the `dist` folder contains the Grunt build results, and if you take a look at the gruntfile you will find all the grunt configuration that makes this possible.

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/gruntFile.js

Answer (score 1):

This is a server side phenomenon. There is a middleware in this file `server/lib/routes/static.js` :

line : 9
`app.use(config.server.staticUrl, express.static(config.server.distFolder));`

What this does is : if any http request is started from `config.server.staticUrl` (whitch is `/static` for this app) the server tries to respond with the resource that are kept in a `config.server.distFolder` folder (which is client/dist for this app).

For example :
when you request to this url `/static/angular.js` the middleware tries to find `angular.js` file in `client/dist/`. Because `client/dist` directory is mapped to the url which starts with `/static` by the middleware.

Comment: This is a great answer, with nice detail. Thanks!